# c# api controller - repeating the same lines over and over

Tags: c#, refactoring, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a BookingController with lots of methods regarding bookings, which get called from the frontend.

An example controller method:

```
public IActionResult DoWhatever(Guid bookingId, DateTime newDeparture)
{
    if (!_bookingRepository.BookingExistsAsync(bookingId)) 
        return NotFound();
    if (!_bookingRepository.IsBookingFromUserAsync(bookingId, User.Identity.Name))
        return Forbid();



   //start unique code, for example
   var bookingEntity = await _bookingRepository.GetBookingAsync(bookingId);


    if (newDeparture <= bookingEntity.Departure)
        return UnprocessableEntity(new ErrorMessage("Booking cant be shortened"));

    if (await _bookingRepository.CollidesWithOtherBookings(bookingEntity, newDeparture))
        return UnprocessableEntity(new ErrorMessage("Booking collides with another Booking"));


    bookingEntity.Departure = newDeparture;
   _bookingRepository.UpdateBooking(bookingEntity);

    return Ok(); 
}
```

Almost all of my methods start with with the first 4 lines.
How can i extract them into a small extra method? I would also like it to be as short as possible. The code inside the dots can contain individual early returns too.

I tried a lot of weird stuff, the best i could come up with is this

```
    private IActionResult CheckExistsAndAccess(Guid bookingId)
    {
        if (!_bookingRepository.BookingExistsAsync(bookingId))
            return NotFound();
        if (!_bookingRepository.IsBookingFromUserAsync(bookingId, User.Identity.Name))
            return Forbid();

        return Ok();
    }
```

Then the calling code can be

```
var returnCode = CheckExistsAndAccess(bookingId);
if (returnCode != Ok())
    return returnCode;
```

Its defintely shorter and i avoid some(lots of) code duplication.

But is this really any cleaner? Something about it feels off to me.

Comment: Take a look to [action filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-3.1#action-filters) in ASP.NET Core

Comment: I also think an Action Filter could be a reasonable solution.